# ¿Cómo definir el color/estilo de cada fila dependiendo del valor de una referencia con OpenXava?

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica, openxava

Tengo una entidad Incidencia con una referencia a una entidad Prioridad. Quiero un color diferente para cada fila dependiendo del valor de prioridad en el modo lista de mi módulo OpenXava .

Este es el código de mi entidad Incidencia:

```
package com.tuempresa.tracker.modelo;

import java.time.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

import org.openxava.annotations.*;
import org.openxava.calculators.*;
import org.openxava.model.*;

import lombok.*;

@Entity @Getter @Setter
public class Incidencia extends Identifiable {

    @Column(length=100) @Required
    String titulo;
            
    @Stereotype("SIMPLE_HTML_TEXT") 
    String descripcion;
    
    @ReadOnly 
    @DefaultValueCalculator(CurrentLocalDateCalculator.class) 
    LocalDate creadoEl;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=true)
    @DescriptionsList
    Prioridad prioridad; 
        
}
```

Y este el de Prioridad:

```
package com.tuempresa.tracker.modelo;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;

import org.openxava.annotations.*;

import lombok.*;

@Entity @Getter @Setter
public class Prioridad {
    
    @Id @Max(9)
    int nivel;
    
    @Column(length=40) @Required
    String descripcion;

}
```

Y este el efecto que quiero conseguir:

[image: Filas resaltadas por valor de referencia en lista]

Fijaos como las filas con prioridad LOW están en gris y las filas con prioridad HIGH están en negrita.

Sé que hay una anotación @RowStyle, pero parece que es para propiedades simples. ¿Cómo puedo definir diferentes estilos para cada fila dependiendo del valor de una referencia (@ManyToOne)?

Answer (score 0):

@RowStyle te permite usar propiedades calificadas, es decir propiedades de una referencia. Por lo que puedes usar @RowStyle dentro de la anotación @Tab en tu entidad, de esta manera:

```
@Entity @Getter @Setter
@Tab(
    rowStyles= {
        @RowStyle(style="alta-prioridad", property="prioridad.nivel", value="7"),
        @RowStyle(style="baja-prioridad", property="prioridad.nivel", value="3"),      
    }
)
public class Incidencia extends Identifiable {
```

Fíjate como para el atributo property en @RowStyle usamos "prioridad.nivel", con lo que referenciamos a una propiedad de la referencia prioridad. Como indicamos arriba cuando prioridad.nivel es 7 aplicamos el estilo alta-prioridad y cuando es 3 aplicamos baja-prioridad. Estos estilos son clases CSS definidas en tu archivo custom.css, así:

```
.alta-prioridad {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.baja-prioridad {
    color: lightgray !important;
}
```

Para aprender más lee la [guía de referencia de OpenXava sobre @RowStyle](https://openxava.org/OpenXavaDoc/docs/tab_es.html#Datos%20tabulares-Propiedades%20iniciales%20y%20resaltar%20filas).